# knockout.js foreach binding within table

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am new to knockout.js and trying to figure why the next code yields exception, while seeming to be valid knockout binding.

```
<table>
    <!-- ko foreach: [] -->
    <tr></tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
</table>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Esfk5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting it into a `<tbody>` seems to resolve the error. [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Esfk5/1/), but to summarize the HTML is:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <!-- ko foreach: [] -->
    <tr></tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```